# LocalBroadcastManager vs Context.registerReceiver(), Context.sendBroadcast(Intent), and Context.unregisterReceiver() are they same?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I was using `Context.registerReceiver(), Context.sendBroadcast(Intent) , and Context.unregisterReceiver()`

but when I saw the class `LocalBroadcastManager`, it has `registerReceiver(), sendBroadcast(Intent) ,`and`unregisterReceiver()` like in `Context`.

I'm confused. When should I use the `LocalBroadcastManager`? are they same in `Context`?

Regards,

Thanks...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

LocalBroadcastManager is as its name says, an implementation of the broadcast methods that are **only** available to your app. This has some benefits, with the biggest being safety, one less hole to watch out for. In terms of implementation, there are a few things to keep in mind:

- This class is from the Android Support Library
- The method calls have to be prefaced with `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance([CONTEXT])` where `[CONTEXT]` is a subclass of the Context class, such as Activity.
- When you use this class, it is purely for **your** app. Using it to register receivers and make broadcasts that are system wide will fail.

So this class is not the same as Context, it is simply a very specific, app-only implementation of Context's receiver/broadcast methods. You should use it when there is absolutely no point for your listener to listen on global (system-wide) broadcasts and when your broadcast does not need to target anything outside your app.

Comment: If I remember right, it's also more efficient than a normal `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Following @Luksprog's comment, it is more efficient as it avoids the IPC overhead since it is limited to the app's process.

Comment: note LocalBroadcastManager can't send a sticky broadcast

Comment: One doubt here..If i am looking for NetworkConnecivitychanges broadcast, can i then use LocalBroadCastReceiver or I will have to use the Context BR ?