# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered

Tags: android

I have TrackingService component to track the location of the buses in my city based on Crowdsourcing. The TrackingService is operating in the background, then the data is transmitted to the server. I have an Map Activity to display the location of the buses, the user selected in the MainActivity( as Filter).

The background TrackingService is started in the MainActivity  when the app launches.

I notifing the `map` activity about the updated lcoation with the aid of the BroadcastReceiver as in the code below. The data is being retrieved to the  the map activity but I am facing problem to unregister my `bReceiver`.  I want to unregister the broadcast when the app goes in the background or when the user presses the back button but I am getting the error below:

How can I fix it?

**Error:**

```
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588): Process: com.bustracker, PID: 19588
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.bustracker/com.bustracker.Map}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.bustracker.Map$1@2483d256
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4156)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4219)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:177)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.bustracker.Map$1@2483d256
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:822)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:2038)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:528)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at com.bustracker.Map.onStop(Map.java:418)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1275)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6493)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4151)
08-27 22:43:04.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19588):    ... 10 more
```

**TrackingService class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements
        LocationListener {
    public double pLong;
    public double pLat;
    ...
        @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        detectLocation();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private void detectLocation() {
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 0,
                this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
        pLong = location.getLongitude();
        pLat = location.getLatitude();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Map.RECEIVE_latLng);
        intent.putExtra("location",location);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
           .....

     }  

}
```

**Map activity:**

```
    public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback   {
   public static final String RECEIVE_latLng = "com.bustracker.RECEIVE_latLng";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        LocalBroadcastManager bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(RECEIVE_latLng);
        bManager.registerReceiver(bReceiver, intentFilter);

    }


    private BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVE_latLng)) {
                              Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra("location");
             double lng = location.getLongitude();
             double lat = location.getLatitude();
             LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
             MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title("My Location")
                        .position(ll);
             System.out.println("ABC map: "+ lat + " ; " + lng);
             myLocatMarker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
            }
          }
        };      
      }
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);      
}
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

If you register in `onCreate()`, you have to unregister in `onDestroy()`. If you want to unregister in `onStop()` you have to register in `onStart()`.

Have a look at the activity lifecycle here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

The reason for this is that `onStop()` is called when the `Activity` goes into the background, but is not necessarily destroyed. When the `Activity` comes back to the foreground `onStart()` is called, but *not* `onCreate()` so the `BroadcastReceiver` isn't re-registered. Then when the `Activity` goes back into the background, `onStop()` tries to unregister again, but the receiver has not been registered.

You also need to use the `LocalBroadcastManager` to unregister your receiver if you used it to register it like so:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
```

`LocalBroadcastManager` is a class from the [support library](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html):

> Helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects within your process.

This is different from the same methods on `Context` which allow system-wide broadcasts.

Also see a similar question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595925/localbroadcastmanager-vs-context-registerreceiver-context-sendbroadcastinten).

Comment: So I have registered the `bReceiver` in the onStart() but I am still getting the error.

Comment: @Mr Asker Can you show the new code and the new stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks, didn't even spot that one. I have updated the answer now. I still believe the comments I made on the lifecycle methods are valid too, so I leave them in there.

Comment: yes, registering on LocalBroadcast but unregistering in Activity context leads to this exception.

Comment: What would be the case in Fragment, if I register in onCreateView() where should i unregister ?

Comment: why is LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(bReceiver); required ?

Answer (score 29):

(Of course, if you want) You may register or unregister them in `onStop()` and `onResume()` just wrap it with try-catch:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume()
    try{ 
        getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver,filter); 
    }catch (Exception e){
        // already registered
    }
}
```

Or

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    try{ 
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);  
    }catch (Exception e){
        // already unregistered
    }
    super.onStop()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Keep in mind that you must register and unregister on the same context.
For example, don't register w/ the application context and unregister w/ the activity context.

Don't do this

```
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(myReceiver, myIntentFilter);
unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

Do this instead (inside an activity)

```
registerReceiver(myReceiver, myIntentFilter);
unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

I normally register inside `onPostResume()` or `onResume()` and unregister in `onPause()`.

Examples:

```
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();

    registerReceiver(myReceiver, myIntentFilter);
}
```

---

```
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);

    //called after unregistering
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: I just want to inform you that you called unregisterReceiver() before super.onPause within your code example. I am not sure which it is you intended.

Answer (score 5):

You have to register a broadcast receiver in `onResume()` and unregistered it in `onPause()` because they will be called for sure before the fragment or the activity is being destroyed for any reasons. If you register a broadcast receiver in `onStart()` and unregistered it in `onStop()`, still works fine, but it has a caveat though. If you use `onStart()` and `onStop()`, you don't have guarantee that broadcast receiver will be unregistered in `onStop()` method b.c of [Android Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

For instance: There are two activities (A & B). When moving from activity A to activity B,  the `onStart()` and `onResume()` of activity B may be called before `onStop()` of activity A, and  the wrong activity which is in this case activity A's method `onStop()` may catch broadcast receiver of activity B and unregistered it, and then when activity B is being closed or invisible, its `onStop()` method is called to unregistere the broadcast receiver that has already being unregistered by `onStop()` method of Activity A, and that causes a crash.

In simple term, even though activity A is invisible, its `onStop()` method still can listen events of activity B. Therefore, if you want to listen only for events when your activity is visible then use `onPause()`  method to unregister a broadcast receiver.

Generally speaking:

register on  `onResume()` unregister `onPause()` guaranteed

register on  `onStart()` unregister `onStop()` not guaranteed due to activity lifecycle.