# I have android app but i startactivity() crahs the app and send me this error unable to pause activity

Tags: java, android

```
if((TypeMov).equals("IN") || (TypeMov).equals("INRW")   ) {
    String query="SELECT *  FROM prods_locations pl inner join inventory inv on inv.pn=pl.pn   where pl.pn = '"+productcode+"' and pl.location='"+locationid+"';";
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
    if (result.next()) {
        Intent newScreen = new Intent(Products.this, MovtoProducts.class);
        String stockprod= result.getString("inv.stockqty");
        String inputsprod= result.getString("inv.incomeqty");
        String outputsprod= result.getString("inv.outgoingqty");
        String locastock= result.getString("pl.stockqty");
        String locainputs= result.getString("pl.incomes");
        String locaoutputs= result.getString("pl.outgoings");
        newScreen.putExtra("productid", productcode);
        newScreen.putExtra("proddesc", result.getString("title"));
        newScreen.putExtra("proddetail", result.getString("detail"));
        newScreen.putExtra("location", locationid);
        newScreen.putExtra("Typemov", TypeMov);
        newScreen.putExtra("stock", stockprod);
        newScreen.putExtra("inputs", inputsprod);
        newScreen.putExtra("outputs", outputsprod);
        newScreen.putExtra("locstock", locastock);
        newScreen.putExtra("locinputs", locainputs);
        newScreen.putExtra("locoutputs", locaoutputs);
        newScreen.putExtra("HostIp", getIntent().getStringExtra("HostIp"));
        newScreen.putExtra("user", getIntent().getStringExtra("User"));
        newScreen.putExtra("psw", getIntent().getStringExtra("Pwd"));
        connection.close();

        startActivity(newScreen);
        finish();
        // activitylancher.launch(newScreen);
    } else{
        Toast errorToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product not found at location ",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        errorToast.show();
    }
```

This is the error message:

```
I/View: Key up dispatch to androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{6ecc362 VFED..CL. .F...... -4,137-487,212 #7f08016e app:id/scanPrompt}, event = KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_KEY_RSCAN, scanCode=114, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=2665409, downTime=2664922, deviceId=7, source=0x101 }
D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 16, 0, 129, 505
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smacstockroom, PID: 5680
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.smacstockroom/com.example.smacstockroom.Products}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.smacstockroom.Products$1@750f15b
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:3835)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3794)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3768)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3742)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1539)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.smacstockroom.Products$1@750f15b
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1012)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1342)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:608)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:608)
        at com.example.smacstockroom.Products.onPause(Products.java:172)
        at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6806)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1322)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:3817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3794) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3768) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1539) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: Please do not spam tags. Choose only the tags that are needed for your code. There is no PHP or javascript here, so I've removed those. Also Delphi, though I was unsure about that one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259429/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-receiver-not-registered)